# I'm using custom CSS to edit the fonts of a website within my streaming Software but I can't get the formatting right to have the font outlined

Tags: html, css, text, fonts

For context:

I'm not hugely knowledgable when it comes to HTML or CSS, but long-story short: I use Streamlabs OBS, it's streaming software, and I'm using its browsersource function to display parts of a website within my stream, in this case I'm displaying a live-updating count of my Twitter followers, I don't like the default font on the website so using the custom CSS option Streamlabs OBS has for browsersources I've changed the font already, but I want to use a function like strokeme or text-shadow in my code, but as someone brand new to this stuff I don't know where to put those paramaters relative to the rest of what I have. Here's what the custom CSS field shows so far from what I have:

```
html *
{
@font-face {
font-family: Rajdhani;
src:local("C:\Users\Briai\Documents\Fonts\Rajdhani\Rajdhani-SemiBold.ttf")
  }


   font-size: 40px;
   color: #000000;
   font-family: Rajdhani;
}
```

I know there are Html functions for getting outlines on text, I've seen a few recommended here, but I don't know where I'd insert those particular functions in this custom CSS field, I know this is an incredibly basic question, but I was hoping someone might be able to help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You cant load font from your PC to the browser of others. They would need a constant access to your files which will for security reasons not work.
But you can can use any Font that is accessible online like with Google Fonts. For that the Font needs to be linked to the CSS file with `@import url""`.

Then you ened to define the Font with for the entire Website with html {font-family: 'Font', sans-serif/serif/cursive;}. Last but not least the `font-size`

The entire code should then look like this (e.g. Josefin Sans from Google Fonts):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans&display=swap');

html {
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I think there's a misunderstanding though, I'm not making a website, I'm broadcasting my display to others via streaming software, so as long as my display shows the right font, seeing as that display is being broadcast.